# Android Media Player and List View - Indian Music Sheets

Tags: android, android-listview, android-mediaplayer

I am an amateur android application developer and now in the process of developing an android application for our music school.

```
Now I'm in the stage to load a mp3 file in an android Media Player, play or stop each song in the list view when the user clicks play or stop button.

![enter image description here][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jUbOB.png

I have stored the mp3 files in res/raw folder. And I have created a class called Song to create data for each of the songs.

Below is the XML file to fill each item in the list view

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tvViewSample"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgFilmPoster"
        android:layout_width="75sp"
        android:layout_height="75sp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/abc_ab_bottom_solid_dark_holo" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvSongName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tvFilmName"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvFilmName"
        android:text="@string/dummy"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvYearReleased"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tvSongName"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvSongName"
        android:text="@string/dummy"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvPrice"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tvYearReleased"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvYearReleased"
        android:text="@string/dummy"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvFilmName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgFilmPoster"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:text="@string/dummy"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgAddCart"
        android:layout_width="35sp"
        android:layout_height="35sp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/add_to_cart"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imgView"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgView"
        android:src="@drawable/add_to_cart"
        android:tag = "@string/add_to_cart" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgView"
        android:layout_width="35sp"
        android:layout_height="35sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imgFilmPoster"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgPlay"
        android:src="@drawable/view_icon" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgPlay"
        android:layout_width="35sp"
        android:layout_height="35sp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tvPrice"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imgView"
        android:contentDescription="@string/play_mp3"
        android:src="@drawable/play" />

</RelativeLayout>

Below is the XML file to display the list view

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#F8AE9F"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        style="@style/aboutComposer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="45sp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/msv_songs"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvCartTotal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@string/cart_total"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvCartTotal"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:src="@drawable/icon_pay_now" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lstMSVSongs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:focusable="false" >

    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Song.class file

```
package com.srindroid.indianmusicsheets;

public class Song {

    private int filmImageID;    
    private String movieName;
    private String songName;
    private String yearReleased;
    private int songPrice;
    private int sampleSheetMusicID;
    private int mp3File;
    private int sheetMusicID;

    public Song(int filmImageID, String movieName, String songName,
            String yearReleased, int songPrice, int mp3File) {
        super();
        this.filmImageID = filmImageID;
        this.movieName = movieName;
        this.songName = songName;
        this.yearReleased = yearReleased;
        this.songPrice = songPrice;
        this.mp3File = mp3File;
    }
    public int getFilmImageID() {
        return filmImageID;
    }
    public String getMovieName() {
        return movieName;
    }
    public String getSongName() {
        return songName;
    }
    public String getYearReleased() {
        return yearReleased;
    }
    public int getSongPrice() {
        return songPrice;
    }
    public int getmp3File() {
        return mp3File;
    }
    public void setFilmImageID(int filmImageID) {
        this.filmImageID = filmImageID;
    }
    public void setMovieName(String movieName) {
        this.movieName = movieName;
    }
    public void setSongName(String songName) {
        this.songName = songName;
    }
    public void setYearReleased(String yearReleased) {
        this.yearReleased = yearReleased;
    }   
    public void setSongPrice(int songPrice) {
        this.songPrice = songPrice;
    }
    public void setSampleSheetMusicID(int sampleSheetMusicID) {
        this.sampleSheetMusicID = sampleSheetMusicID;
    }
    public void setMp3File(int mp3File) {
        this.mp3File = mp3File;
    }
    public void setSheetMusicID(int sheetMusicID) {
        this.sheetMusicID = sheetMusicID;
    }



}
```

MsvSongs.class file

```
package com.srindroid.indianmusicsheets;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.srindroid.indianmusicsheets.R.drawable;

public class MsvSongs extends Activity {

    int cart_total; 
    MediaPlayer mp3Player = null;

    private List<Song> msvSongs = new ArrayList<Song>();    

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {        
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        setContentView(R.layout.msv_music_sheets);
        populateSongsList();
        populateSongsListView();
    }

    private void populateSongsList() {
        msvSongs.add(new Song(R.drawable.ayirathil_oruvan,"Aayirathil Oruvan","Aadho Andha Paravai Pola","1975",250,R.raw.adho_andha_paravai_pola));
        msvSongs.add(new Song(R.drawable.server_sundaram,"Server Sundaram","Avalukku Enna Azhagiya Mugam","1964",175,R.raw.avalukkenna_azhagiamugham));     
    }

    private void populateSongsListView() {
        ArrayAdapter<Song> msvSongs = new MSVSongsAdapter();
        ListView songsList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lstMSVSongs);
        songsList.setAdapter(msvSongs);

    }

    private class MSVSongsAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Song>{
        public MSVSongsAdapter(){
            super(MsvSongs.this, R.layout.songs_view, msvSongs);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View itemView = convertView;
            if(itemView == null){
                itemView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.songs_view, parent, false);         
            }

            for(int i=0;i<msvSongs.size();i++){
                //Find a song to display
                final Song currentSong = msvSongs.get(position);

                //Fill the FilmPoster View
                ImageView filmPoster = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgFilmPoster);
                filmPoster.setImageResource(currentSong.getFilmImageID());  

                //Fill the FilmName View
                TextView filmName = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvFilmName);
                filmName.setText(currentSong.getMovieName());

                //Fill the SongName View
                TextView songName = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvSongName);
                songName.setText(currentSong.getSongName());

                //Fill the YearReleased View
                TextView yearReleased = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvYearReleased);
                yearReleased.setText(currentSong.getYearReleased());

                //Fill the Price View
                TextView songPrice = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvPrice);
                songPrice.setText("Rs. "+currentSong.getSongPrice());

                //Fill the Play MP3 View
                final ImageView viewMP3 = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgPlay);               
                viewMP3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {                 


                    **@Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        String contentDesc = (String) viewMP3.getContentDescription();                      
                        if(contentDesc.contains("Play")){                           
                            mp3Player = MediaPlayer.create(MsvSongs.this, currentSong.getmp3File());
                            mp3Player.start();
                            viewMP3.setImageResource(drawable.stop);                            
                            viewMP3.setContentDescription("Stop MP3");
                            Toast.makeText(MsvSongs.this, "Playing MP3", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();    
                        }else{              
                            mp3Player.pause();
                            mp3Player.stop();
                            viewMP3.setImageResource(drawable.play);                                
                            viewMP3.setContentDescription("Play MP3");
                            Toast.makeText(MsvSongs.this, "Stopping MP3", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }

                        }
                });**

                //Fill the View Sample View
                ImageView viewSample = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgView);
                viewSample.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Toast.makeText(MsvSongs.this, R.raw.he_is_a_pirate, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();                      
                    }
                });

                //Fill the Add To Cart View
                final ImageView viewCart = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgAddCart);               
                final TextView cartTotal = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvCartTotal);
                viewCart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {                       
                        String contentDesc = (String) viewCart.getContentDescription();
                        if(contentDesc.contains("Add")){
                            viewCart.setImageResource(drawable.remove_from_cart);   
                            viewCart.setContentDescription("Remove From Cart");
                            cart_total=cart_total+(currentSong.getSongPrice());
                            cartTotal.setText("Your cart total is Rs. "+cart_total);
                        }else{
                            viewCart.setImageResource(drawable.add_to_cart);
                            viewCart.setContentDescription("Add To Cart");
                            cart_total=cart_total-(currentSong.getSongPrice());
                            cartTotal.setText("Your cart total is Rs. "+cart_total);
                        }

                    }
                });

            }           
            return itemView;            
        }       

    }
}
```

Now the problem I face with the above code is that, when the user clicks the Play button of the first song, the media player plays it as expected. And when the user clicks the Play button of the second song, the media player plays it without stopping the first song. I used mp3Player.isPlaying(), which is always returning FALSE even when the song is actually being played.

Could you please help me with this?

Below is the code that I have written to play or stop each song in the list view

final ImageView viewMP3 = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgPlay);
                viewMP3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

```
                **@Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    String contentDesc = (String) viewMP3.getContentDescription();                      
                    if(contentDesc.contains("Play")){                           
                        mp3Player = MediaPlayer.create(MsvSongs.this, currentSong.getmp3File());
                        mp3Player.start();
                        viewMP3.setImageResource(drawable.stop);                            
                        viewMP3.setContentDescription("Stop MP3");
                        Toast.makeText(MsvSongs.this, "Playing MP3", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();    
                    }else{              
                        mp3Player.pause();
                        mp3Player.stop();
                        viewMP3.setImageResource(drawable.play);                                
                        viewMP3.setContentDescription("Play MP3");
                        Toast.makeText(MsvSongs.this, "Stopping MP3", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                    }
            });*
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I don't see you using mp3player.isPlaying() anywhere in your code. Did you delete it?

It seems like you're testing whether the song related to the ImageView is playing or not. You do not check whether another song is playing or not when you create your MediaPlayer.

Try that:

```
if(contentDesc.contains("Play")){                           
    if (mp3Player != null && mp3Player.isPlaying()) {
       mp3Player.pause();
       mp3Player.stop();
       mp3Player.release();
    }
    mp3Player = MediaPlayer.create(MsvSongs.this, currentSong.getmp3File());
    mp3Player.start();
    ...  
}else{              
    mp3Player.pause();
    mp3Player.stop();
    mp3Player.release();
}
```

Please don't forget to release your MediaPlayer before making a new one.

Comment: How about changing the images for start and pause back and forth?